# private method issue c# (change color from tool strip menu item)

Tags: c#, methods, private

I have a logic issue on a tic tac toe game.
I want to add a new feature.
When I click on "Yellow Color" in the menu, I want my red cross to become yellow when the cursor enters the button.

I can't see the variable "b" from the following method, so I was wondering how should I do that.

```
private void yellowColorToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    b.ForeColor= System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
} //syntax error

private void button_enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    if (b.Enabled)
    {
        if (turn)
        {
            b.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            b.Text = "X";
        }
        else
        {
            b.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            b.Text = "O";
        }
    }
}
```

I couldn't find anything on the net

Comment: Could you please describe more. You may have variable b defined in the top. or post the code(if Possible)

Comment: The source code of the app is too long for posting it all, I've added many functions. The variable b isn't defined anywhere else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've declared a *local variable* in the `button_enter` method. That variable is *only* available within the method. If you want that variable to be part of the start of the instance, you need to make it an *instance* variable, declared outside any method.

However, it sounds like the *real* state that you want isn't another button reference - it's "the colour to set the foreground to when the cursor enters the button". So you might have:

```
private Color entryColor;

private void yellowColorToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    entryColor = Color.Yellow;
}

private void button_enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = (Button) sender;
    if (b.Enabled)
    {
        if (turn)
        {
            b.ForeColor = entryColor;
            b.Text = "X";
        }
        else
        {
            b.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
            b.Text = "O";
        }
    }
}
```